# How do I restore my console default font, and why has it changed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, console, fonts

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10, and I use my console a lot. Today I discovered that its font was changed; specifically, this screen is from yesterday:

[image: yesterday]

and this is from today:

[image: today]

First of all, any idea of how I changed it? I'm pretty sure I did nothing to justify this, but I'm also certain that if something happened there's always a reason, so...

Besides, how do I restore the previous font? The main issue is that I'm not sure what it was.

Comment: My guess is that you hit a key combination that told the terminal to increase the font size.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no way to change the font size with a key combination; actually, as far as I can see the only way to change the font is by modifying something on grub, so, well, I'm kinda confident I didn't do anything like that.

Comment: What files in `/etc` have been modified since the last reboot? Did you reboot since yesterday? What did you do before to set the console font: are you using a font on the graphic card, or the framebuffer?

Answer (score 6):

I'm wondering why you chose a bunch of dots and arrows to demonstrate a font instead of... you know... letters.

Anyway the command for changing font on the VTs is `setfont` or `consolechars`. Running `setfont` with no args or `consolechars -d` loads a "default" font. Others that you can load are found in `/usr/share/consolefonts`.

In Debian there's a file `/etc/default/console-setup` which the boot scripts use to decide what to do with the console font.

Comment: Of course, matching an old screenshot made for a different purpose makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reset` command in bash to reset everything in your shell, such as color and so on.

Comment: Oh ,So you didn't changed font already , and you want to change now ... ok? or default font deleted.

Comment: What command works in dash?

Comment: @neverMind9 `reset` command works in `dash`.

Comment: Surprisingly, it does not work in `jackpal.androidterm`. Android Terminal uses Bash. Is there any alternative that works in Android Terminal?

Comment: I remember android used `mksh` @neverMind9